# skipuntil including match in Where method

Tags: csv, powershell

Good day,

I have below script:

```
$firstline = "Some text"
$csvpre = $csvimport.Where({ $_ -like "$firstline" },'SkipUntil')
```

This deletes all rows until, but not including, row equal to "Some text"

Is there a way to also delete the matching row?

Many thanks

Comment: Pipe to `| Select -Skip 1`?

Comment: Indeed, thanks MadTech